# Liquibase ignores databasechangelog table content

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I wrote two migrations with some changeSets (createTable, and ForeignKey constraint). I can execute the migration, if my database is empty it works, my tables are created and the foreignKey is set as well.

Now when I rerun my migrations, it should skip the previous ones but it doesn't. When I verify the databasechangelog, the data are here (2 rows).

Even if I try to verify the content "[listUnrunChangeSets](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/Liquibase.html#listUnrunChangeSets-liquibase.Contexts-liquibase.LabelExpression-)" function, my changeSets are there too. I don't understand why liquibase ignore previous executed migrations.

I'm using the v3.8.5.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share how you are running liquibase - the exact commands used?

Comment: After investigations, I found out that changeSets are not listed well when I execute `listUnrunChangeSets()` in a Spring service. I'm trying to make a guard which will prevent the execution if the database is not up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve the solution, `spring.initialization-mode` was set with `always`.